# Generate time sequence of a day with a minute difference in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I want to generate time sequence of a day by a minute difference using R like

```
00:00, 00:01, 00:02, ..., 23:59
```

For the same, I am using `timeBasedSeq` function of [xts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) package with following lines of code

```
timerange1<- paste('T00:00','/','T23:59',' 12:00',sep="")
timeBasedSeq(timerange1)
```

But, I am not able to generate the sequence with this. Also, I do not understand what `12:00` mean in first line of code, *i.e.,* how does it relate to minutes or hours or seconds.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try with `seq.POSIXct` ie. `format(seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), length.out=10,  by='1 min'), '%H:%M')`

Comment: You don't respect the required format: `CCYYMMDD HHMMSS`.

Comment: @akrun - that is affected by timezone issues, beware. I.e. - it starts at 10am for me here in UTC+10

Comment: @thelatemail If it is just to create that vector `format(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00", tz="GMT"), length.out=10,  by='1 min'), '%H:%M')#
 [1] "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05" "00:06" "00:07" "00:08"
[10] "00:09"`

Comment: ...with `length.out=1440` to get the whole day :-)

Comment: It should be `format(timeBasedSeq("20160106 0000/20160106 2359"), "%H:%M")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't respect the required format: `CCYYMMDD HHMMSS`, in your case `CCYYMMDD HHMM`. Try:

```
library(xts)
timerange1 <- "20160106 0000/20160106 2359"
seqMinute <- format(timeBasedSeq(timerange1), "%H:%M")
length(seqMinute)
# [1] 1440
range(seqMinute)
# [1] "00:00" "23:59"
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what does `four zeros` in second line of code stand for

Comment: I explain this in the first line of the answer. It is Midnight.

Comment: First 2 "0" are the hour. Second 2 "0" are minutes, as said in the first sentence of the answer. So "0000" is Midnight. And "2359" is... 23:59.

Answer (score 11):

Or from the comments,

```
format(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00", tz="GMT"), 
                length.out=1440, by='1 min'), '%H:%M')
```