# specify start and end of time series

Tags: r, datetime

I found some nice code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647685/generate-time-sequence-of-a-day-with-a-minute-difference-in-r) that lets me output a vector of times 00:00:00 to 00:00:00 over 24 hours:

```
format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "60 min"), "%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

Gives:

```
[1] "00:00:00" "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "03:00:00" "04:00:00" "05:00:00" "06:00:00" "07:00:00" "08:00:00"
[10] "09:00:00" "10:00:00" "11:00:00" "12:00:00" "13:00:00" "14:00:00" "15:00:00" "16:00:00" "17:00:00"
[19] "18:00:00" "19:00:00" "20:00:00" "21:00:00" "22:00:00" "23:00:00" "00:00:00"
```

But I want to specify start and end times of the sequence.  I imagine I can insert something like this, which I could not get to work with `seq.POSIXt`:

```
from="17:00:00", to="08:00:00",
```

How might I get a nice vector that looks like that below? Thanks very much.

```
17:00:00, 18:00:00, ..., 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()-7/24), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+8/24), by = "60 min"), "%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

Output:

```
 [1] "17:00:00" "18:00:00" "19:00:00" "20:00:00" "21:00:00" "22:00:00" "23:00:00" "00:00:00" "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "03:00:00" "04:00:00"
[13] "05:00:00" "06:00:00" "07:00:00" "08:00:00"
```

Note, all I did was substract `7/24` (because 17:00 is seven hours before midnight), and add `8/24` because we want to keep the first eight hours after midnight.